# partial class constructor not calling the base

Tags: c#, constructor, partial-classes

MyClass.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
  public partial class MyClass
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
      Name = "base";
    }
  }
}
```

MyClass2.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
  public partial class MyClass
  {
    public MyClass(string nothing) : base()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MyClass myClass = new("str");

      Console.WriteLine(myClass.Name);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this program, myClass.Name was not set by the base constructor.  I put a breakpoint in the parameterless constructor is it was not called from the parameter'ed constructor.  Any idea if this is allowed?  If so, what did I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you're mixing inheritance with partial classes.

Comment: ` : base()` this is calling `Object` constructor (the base class).

Comment: You should be using `: this()`, not `: base()`.

Comment: I hope this article can remain available...though it's closed.  Sometime, it's not what you know or don't know, but what you think you know is actually not what is.  Google can only be helpful when you ask the "right" question.  Kind of like spell checker, it wouldn't tell you about your semantic error.  Not everyone has access to a support group to help w/ this kind topic.  That's why stackoverflow is so valuable.  Thanks to everyone who helped w/ this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your constructor with parameters to invoke another one in the same object you should use `this` keyword, not `base`:

```
public MyClass(string nothing) : this()
{
}
```

In your code `base` will invoke parameterless constructor of base class which is [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.-ctor?view=net-5.0).